# Most efficient way to query the database to get back relational data when one table relates multiple times to another

Tags: mysql

Table A has four 6 fields (id, level, refNum1, refNum2, refNum3, refNum4)
Table B is a look up table (id, num, meaning)

The intention of the query is get back what the meaning is for all four refNums where an id or level is supplied. (There can be multiple results for each level. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B where level = 1 :: could return 10 for instance.)

Currently, I'm getting the answer I want by doing...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE level = 1)e, B AS a, B AS b, B AS c, B AS d
WHERE e.refNum1 = a.num && e.refNum2 = b.num && e.refNum3 = c.num && e.refNum4 = d.num
```

This seems inefficient

1) What are better ways of doing this?
  2) Is there a terminology for this kind of query? (I didn't know what to search for)
  3) Is this just bad schema design? How should it be done if so?

Answer (score 0):

Use a more readable syntax, and you should use joins and try to reduce the need of them. Maybe something like this should work ! It only uses one join

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.level, 
    a.refNum1, 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.refNum1 = b.num THEN b.meaning
        ELSE NULL
    END AS meaning1,
    a.refNum2, 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.refNum2 = b.num THEN b.meaning
        ELSE NULL
    END AS meaning2,
    a.refNum3, 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.refNum3 = b.num THEN b.meaning
        ELSE NULL
    END AS meaning3,
    a.refNum4,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.refNum4 = b.num THEN b.meaning
        ELSE NULL
    END AS meaning4,
FROM A a,
INNER JOIN B b ON a.refNum1 = b.num OR a.refNum2 = b.num OR a.refNum3 = b.num OR a.refNum4 = b.num
WHERE a.level = 1
```

This way you can have the results on different rows. I need to see more in detail the DB, but it should be faster.

If not this is similar to your query, it should output the same result:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.level, 
    a.refNum1, 
    b1.meaning AS meaning1,
    a.refNum2, 
    b2.meaning AS meaning2,
    a.refNum3, 
    b3.meaning AS meaning3,
    a.refNum4,
    b4.meaning AS meaning4,
FROM A a,
INNER JOIN B b1 ON a.refNum1 = b1.num
INNER JOIN B b2 ON a.refNum2 = b2.num 
INNER JOIN B b3 ON a.refNum3 = b3.num
INNER JOIN B b4 ON a.refNum4 = b4.num
WHERE a.level = 1
```